# JVM can't find custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have created a custom Java ClassLoader but I can't get the JVM to load it. I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when I launch the application. The JAR that contains my code is added to the CLASSPATH as an argument to the JVM. Now I am wondering if I have the JAR in the correct place...do ClassLoaders get added here? I know that application code gets added to the CLASSPATH, but one could argue if a custom ClassLoader is application code or internal to the JVM. So, any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Ok, after thinking about this more, I think I may asking the JVM to do something circular. The ClassLoader I have created is a system class loader. These class loaders are the ones that search CLASSPATH for classes to load...but I have put the class loader itself there! So, if I'm correct, where do custom class loaders go?

Comment: Along with your other classes.  Those needing to be loaded must NOT be on your classpath already.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the second part of your answer?

Comment: http://www.exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.lang/LoadClass.html

Comment: I'm not following. To be clear: I have created a custom class loader and specified it to the JVM with the option `-Djava.system.class.loader=com.blah.MyClassLoader`. Then I have added the JAR that contains MyClassLoader to the CLASSPATH, but the JVM complains it cannot find MyClassLoader.

Comment: @Boon That's the correct procedure at a high-level.  You could try `javap -classpath x.jar com.blah.MyClassLoader` to verify that MyClassLoader is packaged properly.  If that works, then I don't know why `java -Djava.system.class.loader=com.blah.MyClassLoader` would not work.